# How do I create a function that creates a list of an attribute from all objects inside a class?

Tags: python

I need a function that collects a specific integer attribute common in all objects inside a class, to then add it to a list to later sum them all up.

Note that the objects created are **not** part of the list originally, but created separately.

```
class Phones:
    def __init__(self, ram):
        self.ram = ram

    def ram_sum(self):
        objs = []
        for i in Phones:
            objs.append(self.ram)
            print(list)



phone_1 = Phones(6)
phone_2 = Phones(6)
phone_3 = Phones(8)

phone_1.ram_sum()
```

But got this error:

`TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable`

I am aware that the Phones I am using inside the for loop may not be supported by the for loop, but I am trying to get the RAM attribute to be collected inside the objs list.

Comment: can you add the whole traceback?

Comment: You don't have a list of objects anywhere; you just have three unrelated references to three objects. `phones = [Phones(6), Phones(6), Phones(8)]; x = [p.ram for p in phones]`.

Comment: Classes do not automatically act as containers for all instances created of the class.

Comment: you are trying to iterate through the class Phones in the for loop, which cant be done, you have to go through an  object which can be iterated.

Comment: I think you have a misconception about what a Class is. When you define a new object/instance that is of the specific class type, you are creating a completely new object. It is just a new object that has the same properties as the class. So a class is just like a frame. So when you create multiple objects they are not related/contained inside the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `Phones` to be able to iterate over every phone object, you might want to define a class attribute that tracks all the instances of the class.

```
class Phones:
    all_phones = []

    def __init__(self, ram):
        self.ram = ram
        self.all_phones.append(self)

    @classmethod
    def ram_sum(cls):
        return sum(p.ram for p in cls.all_phones)



phone_1 = Phones(6)
phone_2 = Phones(6)
phone_3 = Phones(8)

print(Phones.ram_sum())  # 20
```

However, a more typical way of doing this kind of thing would be to simply put the objects in a list as you create them, rather than having every object "know about" every other instance of that class:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Phone:
    ram: int

def ram_sum(phones: list[Phone]) -> int:
    return sum(p.ram for p in phones)

phones = [
    Phone(6),
    Phone(6),
    Phone(8),
]
print(ram_sum(phones))  # 20
```

If you really wanted an object to be in charge of managing all of the phones, it might be better for that to be different from the class of the phone object itself:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Phone:
    ram: int

class Phones:
    def __init__(self):
        self._phones: list[Phone] = []
    
    def add(self, ram: int) -> Phone:
        phone = Phone(ram)
        self._phones.append(phone)
        return phone

    def ram_sum(self) -> int:
        return sum(p.ram for p in self._phones)

phones = Phones()
phone_1 = phones.add(6)
phone_2 = phones.add(6)
phone_3 = phones.add(8)

print(phones.ram_sum())  # 20
```